# RxJS sequential delay between emissions

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, observable, reactive-programming

I have a Observable `observableA`. How can I create another Observable `observableB` which emits value from `observableA`, but the time between each emission is at least 1000 milliseconds?
For example:

```
observableA:  X...500ms..Y..1500ms..Z...600ms..T  
observableB:  X..1000ms..Y..1500ms..Z..1000ms..T
```

Comment: This sound like you should rethink that you are trying to do and maybe describe your actual use case. Operators that come to mind which do similar things would be `delayWhen` `bufferTime` `debounceTime` which either require you to know how many values you are going to recieve, group values or ignore values. You run into problems here if there can be many and more values in `obsA` just because of your approach your would need to `buffer` all the values not emitted yet. maybe emit one every 1000 ms or something like that?

Answer (score 3):

You can always use a silent timer as a lower bound for each new emission length. Then concatMap will handle back pressure for you.

```ts
const bound = timer(1000).pipe(ignoreElements());
const observableB = observableA.pipe(
  concatMap(v => merge(of(v), bound))
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [interval](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/interval) and [zip](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination/zip) to create an observable that fires 1000ms after every value on observableA, and then zip it with observableA -

```
const observableA = create(subscriber => {
  window.setTimeout(() => {
    subscriber.next(1);
    window.setTimeout(() => {
      subscriber.next(2);
        window.setTimeout(() => {
          subscriber.next(3);
          subscriber.complete();    
      }, 500);                                     
    }, 1500);                                          
  }, 600);
});
const delay = concat(from([undefined]), observableA).pipe(
  flatMap(() => interval(1000).take(1)) 
);
const observableB = zip(observableA, delay).map(([first]) => first);
observableB.subscribe((val) => {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(val) + " " + Date.now());
});
```

If you don't want to delay the first value, you can instead do

```
const delay = concat(from([undefined]), observableA.pipe(
  flatMap(() => interval(1000).take(1)) 
));
```

To add an immediate first value.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to put it into a single chain you could use the following using `connect()` operator:

```
const obsA$ = range(5).pipe(
  concatMap((v) => of(v).pipe(delay(Math.random() * 2000)))
);

const MIN_DELAY = 1000;
let observerReceivedTime = new Date().getTime();

obsA$
  .pipe(
    startWith(null),
    connect((shared$) => {
      let lastEmissionTime = null;

      return shared$.pipe(
        concatMap((value) => {
          let delayedValue$;

          if (!lastEmissionTime) {
            // Don't delay the first emission.
            delayedValue$ = of(value);
          } else {
            const delayBetweenValues = new Date().getTime() - lastEmissionTime;

            // Wait for at least `MIN_DELAY`.
            delayedValue$ =
              delayBetweenValues > MIN_DELAY
                ? of(value)
                : of(value).pipe(delay(MIN_DELAY - delayBetweenValues));
          }

          return delayedValue$.pipe(
            // Remember time when the last value was reemited.
            tap(() => (lastEmissionTime = new Date().getTime())),
          );
        })
      );
    })
  )
  .subscribe((v) => {
    const now = new Date().getTime();
    console.log(
      `observer receives emission with at least ${MIN_DELAY}ms delay:`,
      now - observerReceivedTime,
      'value:',
      v
    );
    observerReceivedTime = now;
  });
```

Live demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-wmfetc?devtoolsheight=60&file=index.ts

I'm using RxJS 7 [`connect()`](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/connect) operator to create a scoped variable `lastEmissionTime` so I don't need to make any side-effects (though the chain would be a little shorter and easier to understand to be honest).

Basically, it's just measuring time between the previous emission and the current one and will adjust `delay()` to always be at least `MIN_DELAY`.

In the observer callback I'm just measuring timestamps to prove that the delay is always at least 1000ms as you wanted.

Edit: This is an alternative using `mergeScan` which is better in my opinion:

```
obsA$
  .pipe(
    startWith(null),
    mergeScan(
      ([_, lastEmissionTime], currValue) => {
        let delayedValue$;

        if (!lastEmissionTime) {
          // Don't delay the first emission.
          delayedValue$ = of(currValue);
        } else {
          const delayBetweenValues = new Date().getTime() - lastEmissionTime;

          // Wait for at least `MIN_DELAY`.
          delayedValue$ =
            delayBetweenValues > MIN_DELAY
              ? of(currValue)
              : of(currValue).pipe(delay(MIN_DELAY - delayBetweenValues));
        }

        return delayedValue$.pipe(
          // Remember time when the last value was reemited.
          map((value) => [value, new Date().getTime()])
        );
      },
      [null, null],
      1 // We need to set concurrency to `1`.
    ),
    map(([value]) => value)
  )
```

Live demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-taeyzx?devtoolsheight=60&file=index.ts